# Formatting Multiple Controls in an Excel UserForm using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, controls, userform

I have had a hunt around and have got to a point where I am almost sorted but can't quite complete.

I have the following:

```
Sub Formats()

    'Form Setup
    '----------------
    With AuditForm
        .BackColor = Grey4
        .BorderColor = Grey1
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .ForeColor = Grey1
        .SpecialEffect = 1
    End With
    
    For Each ctrl In AuditForm.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
            ctrl.BackColor = White
            ctrl.BorderColor = Grey1
            ctrl.SpecialEffect = 1
            ctrl.BorderStyle = 1
            ctrl.Font.Name = "Arial"
            
    ElseIf TypeName(ctrl) = "Frame" Then
            ctrl.BackColor = Grey4
            ctrl.BorderColor = Grey1
            ctrl.SpecialEffect = 1
            ctrl.BorderStyle = 1
            ctrl.Font.Name = "Arial"
            ctrl.ForeColor = Grey1
            ctrl.Font.Bold = True
            
    ElseIf TypeName(ctrl) = "Label" Then
            ctrl.BackColor = Grey4
            ctrl.BorderColor = Grey4
            ctrl.SpecialEffect = 1
            ctrl.BorderStyle = 1
            ctrl.Font.Name = "Arial"
            ctrl.ForeColor = Grey1
            ctrl.Font.Bold = True
            
    ElseIf TypeName(ctrl) = "ComboBox" Then
            ctrl.BackColor = White
            ctrl.BorderColor = Grey1
            ctrl.SpecialEffect = 1
            ctrl.BorderStyle = 1
            ctrl.Font.Name = "Arial"
            ctrl.ShowDropButtonWhen = fmShowDropButtonWhenFocus
            ctrl.Style = fmStyleDropDownList
    End If
        
    Next ctrl
        
End Sub
```

I have each control type I need in the code, but I just want to change the:

```
For Each ctrl In AuditForm.Controls
```

To reference any user form that opens. I have tried `For Each ctrl In me.controls` but that seems to error out. The alternative is to copy the block above for each of the userforms in my document, which seems messy.

Any help as ever will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Bill

Comment: It appears you want this code to work for any UserForm.  That being the case, you could pass in the UserForm:  `Sub Formats(ByRef uf As UserForm)`.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand how to put this into play. I am still a newbie.  So I would have:  

`Sub Formats(ByRef uf As UserForm)  
  
     With uF  
        .BackColor = Grey4  
        .BorderColor = Grey1  
        .Font.Name = "Arial"  
        .ForeColor = Grey1  
        .SpecialEffect = 1  
    End With  
  
End Sub`


Something like this instead?

Comment: Yes.  You will replace `AuditForm` with `uf`.

Answer (score 0):

Bill, just declare your ctrl variable as MSForms.Control

```
Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
   ' it works !
Next
```